# SQL Server window function for running percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know there are several examples of recursion with CTE and so on, but how can this be accomplished just by using window functions in SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
       ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       Percentage INT NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @Calculated MONEY = 1000

INSERT INTO #temp ( Percentage ) VALUES  ( 100 )
INSERT INTO #temp ( Percentage ) VALUES  ( 90)
INSERT INTO #temp ( Percentage ) VALUES  ( 60)
INSERT INTO #temp ( Percentage ) VALUES  ( 50)
INSERT INTO #temp ( Percentage ) VALUES  ( 100)
```

And the result would be a running percentage like so (we are starting with $1000)

```
id    percentage   calculated 
--    --------     ---------
1     100          1000        
2     50           500
3     90           450
4     80           360  
5     100          360
```

So the value for the next row is the percentage multiplied by the calculated value above that row. Can LAG be used on a computed alias?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a running product of the percentages instead of always comparing 2 consecutive rows, which is why LEAD and LAG won't work here.

You can use a windowed sum to keep a running product of the percentages against your variable to get your desired calculation:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Expected,
    EXP(SUM(LOG(CONVERT(FLOAT, Percentage) / 100)) OVER (ORDER BY ID)) * @Calculated AS Actual
FROM #Temp
```

Adding this to your sample code (with a column I added for your expected output):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
       ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       Percentage INT NOT NULL,
       Expected MONEY NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @Calculated MONEY = 1000

INSERT INTO #temp ( Percentage, Expected ) VALUES  ( 100 , 1000)
INSERT INTO #temp ( Percentage, Expected ) VALUES  ( 50, 500)
INSERT INTO #temp ( Percentage, Expected ) VALUES  ( 90, 450)
INSERT INTO #temp ( Percentage, Expected ) VALUES  ( 80, 360)
INSERT INTO #temp ( Percentage, Expected ) VALUES  ( 100, 360)

SELECT
    ID,
    Expected,
    EXP(SUM(LOG(CONVERT(FLOAT, Percentage) / 100)) OVER (ORDER BY ID)) * @Calculated AS Actual
FROM #Temp
```

This will yield your expected output:

```
ID          Expected              Actual
----------- --------------------- ----------------------
1           1000.00               1000
2           500.00                500
3           450.00                450
4           360.00                360
5           360.00                360
```

Comment: Too bad there is no built-in aggregate for `PRODUCT()`.

Comment: Yes, you'd think MS might add it by now. I believe Oracle has it or a much cleaner workaround .

Answer (score 0):

you can use `recursive cte` to get the desired result

```
with cte
as
(
select id, percentage, 1000 as calculated 
from #temp 
where id =1
union all
select t.id, t.percentage, t.percentage*cte.calculated/100 as calculated
from #temp  t
join cte
on t.id = cte.id+1
)
select * from cte
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly using a CTE, but I am wondering if it is possible to accomplish this a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, widow functions won't help here (at least they won't make it simple). The easiest way to achieve your goal is update statement with double assignment:

```
alter table #temp add VAL decimal

declare @val decimal = 1000

update t set
  @val = VAL = @val * Percentage / 100
from (select top 100 percent * from #temp order by id) as t

select * from #temp
```